# What's wrong with this code trying to get the element nearest to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script (JavaScript and jquery) is not functioning right.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
mycars = {};

function dodat(){
var btn=document.createElement("div");
btn.style.width="25px";
btn.style.height="25px";
btn.style.backgroundColor="red";
btn.style.boxShadow="inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black";
btn.style.position="absolute";
btn.style.left="0px";
var numba = Math.round(Math.random()*10000000000);
btn.id=numba;
mycars[numba] = -100;

var move = function(){
mycars[numba] = mycars[numba]+1;
document.getElementById(numba).style.left=mycars[numba]+"px";
};

setInterval(move, 10);

document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
}
</script>

<body>

<div style="background-color:#c3c3c3;width:500px;height:25px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;" id="track"></div>

<div id="shoot"></div>
</body>

<script>
setInterval("dodat();", "1000");
</script>

<script>
function dis(){
// Let's find the closest block!
var otherEls = $('div:not(#shoot):not(#track)'),
    compareTop = compareEl.offset().top,
    compareLeft = compareEl.offset().left,
    winningScore = Infinity,
    score, winner, curEl;

otherEls.each(function() {
    // Calculate the score of this element
    curEl = $(this);
    score = Math.abs(curEl.offset().top - compareTop) + Math.abs(curEl.offset().left - compareLeft);
    if (score < winningScore) {
        winningScore = score;
        winner = this;
    }
});

alert('' + winner.id + '. Let me colour it green for you.');
}
setTimeout("dis();", "1000");
</script>
```

The last part of the script tries to utilize jQuery to get the elements closest to `#shoot`, however I must be doing something wrong. Thank you so much :) I want to know what's wrong! I evaled the function, in case if that was the problem.

Comment: you shouldn't use id starting from numbers

Comment: That can't be the problem, I've used numbers before @shadow

Comment: Are you using the `setTimeout()` call at the bottom to wait for the DOM to load, and then start running the program? If so, there is a better way to do that -- use `$(document).ready( function() { ... } );` or its shortcut method `$( function() { ... } );`

Comment: Your next problem, I think, is that you haven't actually included a reference to jQuery. Add this line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

Comment: `setInterval("dodat();", "1000");` should be `setInterval(dodat, "1000");` and `setTimeout("dis();", "1000");` should be `setTimeout(dis, "1000");`

Comment: Next problem: `mycars`.  Is that supposed to be an array, or an object? You are declaring it as an object, but then using it as an array. That is actually legal in Javascript. This statement: `myObj.someProperty = 0;` is equivalent to this one: `myObj['someProperty'] = 0;`  (The assignment to `0` in this example is arbitrary.) But if, as I suspect, it is supposed to be an array, you are using it wrong.

Comment: The problem though is with the last part of the code, everything before it works fine when i isolate it

Comment: `dodat` shows as undefined for me when it's at the end of the document, but not when it's inside of the script. and `compareEl` was also showing as undefined, so I changed it to `otherEls` which is defined. http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/Va7NU/

Answer (score 0):

Multiple errors. compareEl was undefined, and your script was running before document ready. Once you fix that, you couldn't use global scope.

Fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/5fJrx/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
mycars = {};
compareEl = $("#shoot");

function dodat() {
    var btn = document.createElement("div");
    btn.style.width = "25px";
    btn.style.height = "25px";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    btn.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black";
    btn.style.position = "absolute";
    btn.style.left = "0px";
    var numba = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000000000);
    btn.id = numba;
    mycars[numba] = -100;

    var move = function () {
        mycars[numba] = mycars[numba] + 1;
        document.getElementById(numba).style.left = mycars[numba] + "px";
    };

    setInterval(move, 10);

    document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
}

setInterval(dodat, 1000);

function dis() {
    // Let's find the closest block!
    var otherEls = $('div:not(#shoot):not(#track)'),
        compareTop = compareEl.offset().top,
        compareLeft = compareEl.offset().left,
        winningScore = Infinity,
        score, winner, curEl;

    otherEls.each(function () {
        // Calculate the score of this element
        curEl = $(this);
        score = Math.abs(curEl.offset().top - compareTop) + Math.abs(curEl.offset().left - compareLeft);
        if (score < winningScore) {
            winningScore = score;
            winner = this;
        }
    });

    alert('' + winner.id + '. Let me colour it green for you.');
}
setTimeout(dis, 1000);
});
```